# ubuntu alienware aurora r7 gpu + intel graphics

Tags: intel-graphics, nvidia-geforce, dual-graphics

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 and ubuntu 16.04 on dell Aurora R7 that has 2 Nvidia 1080ti GPU's + 1 intel HD graphics cards.

In windows I have video outputs from all graphics cards working. Please, I would like to know why do I have video signal available only from 1 nvidia GPU ? When I plug the displayport on the intel or on the second GPU I have no signal on the screen. This is for both ubuntu 14 and 16.

I updated this question to include the outputs from commands "lspci" and "xranr" below :

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b06] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:3600]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
--
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b06] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:3600]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384


$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 433mm x 270mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'` and `xrandr`? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @DavidFoerster, I've updated my question with your instructions. Regards.

Comment: The integrated Intel graphics adapter doesn't appear anywhere. Did you disable it in BIOS? However, there appear to be more display connections than would typically exist on a single graphics adapter, indicating that both Nvidia cards are working. Did you try to change the display configuration in the system display settings or the Nvidia settings application? Are additional monitors connected to the other card listed there?

Comment: Each 1080ti has 3 DP and 1 hdmi connectors. There is 1 hdmi missing in xrandr output. The intel UHD 630 has 1 DP output that is not showing in xrandr. I have only one display connected that I connect manually and alternatively to other outputs in order to check if I have a signal.  I have looked into system display and nvidia settings (which, btw, has no prime option) but afaiu there is nothing I can do to activate the intel graphics.

Comment: I am suspecting something, but I hope I am wrong. In order to install ubuntu on this computer that is equipped with 1 ssd drive and 1 hdd, I had to go with the hdd since I miserably failed to install on ssd. As a consequence, I am booting in legacy mode. When I boot in UEFI it boots from ssd and starts windows. Can this be the reason behind my problem ?

Comment: @DavidFoerster : I forgot, I can't see any BIOS option where I can act on activating intel graphics or any graphics option.

Comment: I don't think the legacy BIOS boot method can have any impact on this. Once the Linux kernel and the graphics driver module are loaded the BIOS doesn't matter in this context. On another note, nothing prevents UEFI installations on secondary or external drives, though in a dual-boot set-up it would be better to add all available operating systems to the EFI boot loader on the primary drive.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am stuck to this issue. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I tried to activate the i915 or i915_bpo drivers by entering : modprobe i915 or modprobe i915_bpo, but this has no effect (the intel graphics still unclaimed).  I have noticed that this command brings some changes to the lsmod output (I see 915 appear here and there), but when I reboot those changes disappear.